# web scraper beautifulsoup different tags in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, tags

im trying to scrape a stock website scrape the sectors and industry (next question) and add it to a csv. I'm getting the info I want for 1 page but the next one is different so that's where I'm stuck

share_details1 = soup.find('a', href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=100") results : Basic Materials
i want to find tags that range from  100 - 1300 going by hundreds like href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=200" 300 400 500 600 and so on to 1300

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv
import requests

LSE = 'https://csimarket.com/stocks/at_glance.php?code=aa'

def get_stocks():
    with open('tickers.csv') as ticker_file:
        return list(map(lambda ticker: ticker.strip(), ticker_file))


def to_csv(stocks):
    with open('stocks.csv', 'w') as sectors:
        writer = csv.writer(sectors)
        writer.writerow(stocks[0].keys())
        for stock in stocks:
            writer.writerow(stock.values())


def get_soup(url):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

def get_sector(ticker):
    soup = get_soup(LSE + ticker)
    try:
        share_details1 = soup.find('a', href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=100")
        messy = share_details1.find("span")
        messy.decompose()
        sector = share_details1.text.strip()

    except:
        print('No sector information availible for ', ticker)
        return {'ticker': ticker, 'sector': ''}

    print(ticker, sector)
    return {'ticker': ticker, 'sector': sector}


def get_industry(ticker):
    soup1 = get_soup(LSE + ticker)
    try:
        share_details1 = soup1.find('a', href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?ind=104")
        messy = share_details1.find("span")
        messy.decompose()
        industry = share_details1.text.strip()

    except:
        print('No industry information availible for ', ticker)
        return {'ticker': ticker, 'industry': ''}

    print(ticker, industry)
    return {'ticker': ticker, 'industry': industry}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    to_csv(list(map(lambda ticker: get_sector(ticker), get_stocks())))
    # to_csv(list(map(lambda ticker: get_industry(ticker), get_stocks())))
```

here is the sample of the csv

```
ticker,sector
A,
AA,Basic Materials
AADI,
AAIC,
AAL,
AAN,
AAOI,
AAON,
AAP,
AAPL,
AAT,
AAU,Basic Materials
AAWW,
AB,
ABB,
ABBV,
ABC,
ABCB,
ABCL,
ABEO,
ABEV,
ABG,
ABIO,
ABM,
ABMD,
ABNB,
ABOS,
ABR,
ABSI,
ABST,
ABT,
ABTX,
ABUS,
ACA,Basic Materials
ACAD,
ACB,
ACC,
ACCD,
ACCO,Basic Materials
ACEL,
ACER,
ACET,
ACEV,
ACGL,
ACH,Basic Materials
ACHC,
ACHR,
ACHV,
ACI,
ACIU,
```

Comment: share a sample of tickers.csv

Comment: hopefully that whill help maybe i didnt explain the problem correctly

Comment: Yes that helps. What are you trying to get exactly. You're sort of over complicating the code. Making a function to to only do 1 or 2 lines of work is unnecessary (like `get_soup(url)`. to then call `soup = get_soup()`. Simply do `soup = bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')` Also makes it harder to debug with excessive functions all over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like those hrefs are dynamic. You're better off just looking for `'Sector'` or `'Industry'` and then parse it.

You could also use regex to pull out that info. But here's my fix.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import re
import requests

LSE = 'https://csimarket.com/stocks/at_glance.php?code='

def get_stocks():
    df = pd.read_csv('tickers.csv')
    return list(df['ticker'])


def to_csv(stocks):
    df = pd.DataFrame(stocks)
    df.to_csv('stocks.csv', index=False)

def get_soup(url):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

def get_sector(ticker):
    soup = get_soup(LSE + ticker)
    try:
        sector = soup.find('span', text='Sector').find_next('a').text.replace('\n','').replace('•','').strip()
    except:
        print('No sector information availible for ', ticker)
        return {'ticker': ticker, 'sector': ''}

    print(ticker, sector)
    return {'ticker': ticker, 'sector': sector}


def get_industry(ticker):
    soup1 = get_soup(LSE + ticker)
    try:
        industry = soup1.find('span', text='Industry').find_next('a').text.replace('\n','').replace('•','').strip()
    except:
        print('No industry information availible for ', ticker)
        return {'ticker': ticker, 'industry': ''}

    print(ticker, industry)
    return {'ticker': ticker, 'industry': industry}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    to_csv(list(map(lambda ticker: get_sector(ticker), get_stocks())))
    # to_csv(list(map(lambda ticker: get_industry(ticker), get_stocks())))
```